# Could not load Kentor.AuthServices. A strongly-named assembly is required

Tags: kentor-authservices

I want to use Kentor.AuthServices to authenticate in my web app using Okta. I followed the article ["How to use KentorIT AuthServices with Okta"](http://developer.okta.com/blog/2016/03/22/use-kentor-authservices-with-okta/).

Because the application would throw an error:

> The signing algorithm http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256 is weaker than the minimum accepted http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1.

That's why I added in `global.asax` following line:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    Kentor.AuthServices.Configuration.Options.GlobalEnableSha256XmlSignatures();
```

This line causes following error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Kentor.AuthServices, Version=0.21.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. A strongly-named assembly is required. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131044)

How to solve this?

Comment: Looks odd that adding the `GlobalEnableSha256XmlSignatures()` would trigger a strong naming conflict. Are you sure it works without it? The AuthServices binaries are not strong named. Have you done anything special? A custom build?